# Switch in function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, function, switch-statement

I wrote this just to learn the switch method, but for some reason it doesn't work as I intended, my function doesn't do anything.
All I wanted to do is write a number in the value, the value then is checked in the switch method, and in case it's greater than zero, display a message, less than zero another message and so on.

Here is the whole thing

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Check if your number in relation to 0</p>

    <input id="in"></input>
  <br>
  <button onclick="check()">Check</button>

  <p id="display"></p>

  <script>

    function check() {

      var text;
      var val = document.getElementById("in").value;

      switch (true) {
        case (val < 0);
          text = "Numarul este mai mic decat zero";
          break;
        case (val > 0);
          text = "Numarul este mai mare decat zero";
          break;
        default:
          text = "Numarul este egal cu zero";
          break;
      }

      document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = text;
    }
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

The text in that language is just saying the number is less greater or equal to zero, doesn't matter, I forgot to translate it in English.

Comment: Learn how to use the console (F12), and you can actually see what the error is.

Comment: Just saying, `switch (true)` is not exactly a best practise. For this use case, you should stay with if-else.

Comment: Do not abuse switch like that. Use if/else, if I remember right, the performance on this is horrible.

Comment: I'm... surprised that parses even with the colons?  Wherever you learned this, it's a bad resource.

Comment: Sorry my question sucks I've gotten much better since then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`case (val > 0);` should be `case (val > 0):`.  You end a case statement with a colon, not semi-colon.

Answer (score 2):

Please change `;` after the case to `:`

```
case val > 0:
//          ^
```

(You do not need parenthesis between `case` and `:`)

Comment: Oh my god, was it that simple, I tried to figure this out for 15 minutes. Thanks guys !